# error auctions.models.Listing.DoesNotExist: Listing matching query does not exist. I am just starting learning django, what is wrong in my code?

Tags: python, django

Here is my views.py file:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import *


def index(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "listings": Listing.objects.all()
    })


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return index(request)


@login_required(login_url='login')
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST["title"]
        description = request.POST["description"]
        price = request.POST["price"]
        picture = request.POST["picture"]
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

        try:
            listing = Listing(item=title, description=description, price=price, image=picture, owner=user)
            listing.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })

        return index(request)
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/new_listing.html")


@login_required(login_url='login')
def listing(request, listing):
    if request.method == "POST":
        bid = request.POST.get("bid")
        try:
            new_bid = listing.get_bids(time=time, user=request.user, price=bid)
            new_bid.save()
        except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("ERROR")
        listing_info = Listing.objects.get(item=listing)
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "listing": listing_info
        })
    else:
        listing_info = Listing.objects.get(item=listing)
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "listing": listing_info
        })


@login_required(login_url='login')
def watchlist(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        product = request.POST.get("product")
        listing_info = Listing.objects.get(item=product)
        watch = Watchlist.objects.filter(product=listing_info, user=user)
        if not watch:
            try:
                new_product = Watchlist(user=user, product=listing_info)
                new_product.save()
            except:
                return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                    "message": "ERROR."
                })
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                "listing": listing_info,
                "message": "Added to watchlist",
                "collor": "green"
            })
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                "listing": listing_info,
                "message": "Already in your watchlist",
                "collor": "red"
            })
    else:
        products = Watchlist.objects.filter(user=user)
        listing_dict = {}
        for product in products:
            listing_dict[product] = Listing.objects.get(item=product.product)
            return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", {
                "products": products,
                "info": listing_dict
            })
```

Not the best and I could've done most of it in better ways but that's how I did it. And this is my Models.py code:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Listing(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owners")
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item


class Bid(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_bids")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_bids")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} put a bid in for {self.price}"


class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="watchlist")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product} by {self.user}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you mistake the code when you post the question but your code is badly indented. You have added two tab space for `User` and `Listing` models. I just removed one tab space and brought it to the normal indentation.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
    
    
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
    
    
class Listing(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owners")
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item

class Bid(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_bids")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_bids")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} put a bid in for {self.price}"

...
```

Comment: That was only in the post. I still get the same error

Comment: Allright, remove the User model you have added and add this import instead and see if it works.

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: Thanks, did that but when I try to make migrations I get "auctions.User.user_ptr: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'."

Comment: So in that field remove the import of User, add

`
from django.conf import settings
and change the model line to

owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_bids")
`

See if it works.

Comment: Remove the import of user? Now I get NameError: name 'User' is not defined.

Comment: `owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_bids") `

Comment: You will have to do it for all of the other models as well that uses User model. The issue is that you have to check exactly how to import the User model from django. Or create a custom User for your own usage and avoid this proble.

Comment: ohh I see. Now I get "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auctions.User' that has not been installed". Do I change settings.py?

Comment: Not sure if it works but how do I fix the register function now if I removed the User class? How do I add new users?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your entire code as is and got no error so far.

Have you tried running

```
python manage.py makemigrations auctions
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

then back to

```
python manage.py runserver
```